# PopCorn Particle Background

Tags: particles, collision

Anyone have an idea of how to make popcorn fill up my screen using practices, or got some video that would help me out, thanks!
I am trying right now, but they keep jumping up and down and not staying in place, how can I fix that at least, would help tons.
Okay an update, I am getting there, but my popcorn right now has no collision, I checked on size deflect, but that's not it. Currently, I have 5000 emitters and it still won't fill up the whole box.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I are almost there!

If you want your background to be static, the important settings are:

- a very high **Number** of particles
- **Frame Start** = **Frame End** = 0
- a very high **Lifetime**
- emit the particles from the **Volume** of a cube, so that the density is even (this is important)
- remove all **Velocity** from the particles
- remove all **Field Weights**

[image]

For the collisions, emitting particles from the volume greatly reduce that problem: the distribution is more even and if you want you can set the **Distribution** (in the *Source* section) to *Grid* and play with the **Random** value

Comment: What I did what generate the popcorn using the particle system and then convert them to actual meshes, and use the rigid body to simulate the rest, I reduced the poly count greatly on em tho.

Comment: Why did you use a rigid body? do you want to make an animation?

Comment: Well yes, I need to fill like an empty box with popcorn and the camera is inside.

Comment: Ah, ok, you should edit your question though, because it seems you want a static image